# Eclipse Java project: can I set eclipse to store .class and .java files in 1 folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, development-environment

I just need a simple environment of .class and .java files in a single folder so that I can execute java files later on using "java xx" in command line without adding any extra syntax.  I'm not planning to use packages or sub-directories in my project and I won't be executing  any files directly from eclipse either.

Comment: use `java -cp class-path xx` while running via command line to pass the classath also

Comment: true, normally I wouldn't do this, but i need to in this case as it was a requirement for a java networking project at school. Plus its only 4 files anyway(and makes use of a few addons which eclipse doesn't have to execute the project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

Create new project->Java Project->In the Project Layout section change to 'User project folder as root for sources and class files' (using Eclipse Kepler, it should be similar in other versions of Eclipse).

But keep in mind that it might become a mess after some time.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a executable jar file and run it from command line using:

`java -jar MyApplication.jar`

Here is the link to create an executable jar file from eclipse:

[How to create an Executable jar file](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm)

Comment: I might actually keep this in mind for future  projects, but I dont think I am allowed to use it in this case.